# Agent VS2017 is stuck at connecting. It never gets out of Queue

Tags: azure-devops

We have tried to run a release a number of time. Agent VS2017 is stuck at connecting. It never gets out of Queue
It gets stuck at:

[image]

Comment: Hi, how about your issue going? Does your puzzle get cleared now with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a issue caused by our side. I think you can also see the message which shows **Waiting for agent cloud to provision agent** in the agent pool page, right?

[image]

This message means the image for hosted agent was being allocated, which will take a longer time if the image hasn't been cached yet in that data center. Our team rolled out a new image last week, which likely the reason for this delay.

You can check https://status.dev.azure.com/_history to follow the latest Pipelines status. During the past few days, Azure Devops have had repeated issues in a few areas, which we have mitigated this issue for now, but still continue to dig in to get the root cause.

[image]

If this issue still occurred and keeping long time, you can go [Ubuntu Hosted Agent Stuck](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576674/ubuntu-hosted-agent-stuck.html), and comment with your **region** and **organization name**. Our engineer will take look this and help you investigate further.